# Sqlite read performance is very slow on network

Tags: sqlite

We have a 120 MB database of sqlite on Local machine its working really fine.but when we are using it on network its reading performance is really slow.

Has anybody encountered the same issue or has some hints ?

Comment: Can be that network are slow

Comment: i tried on multiple networks still its not working.

Comment: From the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) (see the first bullet under "Situations Where A Client/Server RDBMS May Work Better"): "SQLite will work over a network filesystem, but because of the latency associated with most network filesystems, performance will not be great. Also, file locking logic is buggy in many network filesystem implementations (on both Unix and Windows)."

Comment: i read this documentation already, but i think it explains only about concurrency problem on network, i think when i am only reading some data, it should perform in a normal way.

Comment: The problem is not that some other computer *does* change the database, but that some other computer *might* have changed the database.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t understand you. Will you please elaborate ?